# React and Fluent UI style - type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'

Tags: reactjs, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I have a Card component from FluentUI library. I want to hover over the card and change the color of the border. This is my attempt to do it but for some reason I am having below error:

> type 'string' is not assignable to type 'undefined'

```
    const useStyles = makeStyles({
        card: {
            width: '100px',
            height: '100px',
            "&:hover": {
                borderRadius: "20px",
                background: "#FF",
                boxShadow: 'another value here',
            },
        },
    });
```

Why all the values that I am trying to initialize in the `&:hover` section are complaining with the same error? How can I initialize them?

Answer (score 1):

It has nothing to do with your `&:hover` selector as such. GriffelJS (the underlying lib in FluentUI) doesn't support CSS shorthands (like background or borderRadius) directly. Thats why their type is `undefined` instead of `string`. You have to use the specific CSS properties instead. For some CSS shorthands GriffelJS also has a helper function you can use:

```
'&:hover': {
    ...shorthands.borderRadius('20px'),
    backgroundColor: '#FF0000',
    boxShadow: '...',
}
```

You find more infos to shorthands in GriffelJS in their documentation [GriffelJS - shorthands](https://griffel.js.org/react/api/shorthands/)

Comment: GriffelJS info was helpful, thanks